# External script with icons loads when the page loads but the icons don't appear

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

First of all thank you very much for reading my question!

I work in a vue file. In the App.vue I import an external .js file with icons like this

```
let recaptchaScript2 = document.createElement('script')
recaptchaScript2.setAttribute('src', '../static/js/uikit-icons.min.js')
document.head.appendChild(recaptchaScript2)
```

When I load the page it the script is loaded.
[image: You can see the chrome network tab here.] But the icons don't show on the page, the  is empty in the elements-tab. Then when I make a small random change in the code, vue "reloads" the page (without a real refresh). And then the icons do show up! [image: You can see the chrome network tab here.]

I thought it maybe because the scripts reload for whatever reason and are then loaded after everything else. But when I add an interval to execute the code that loads the script 500ms later, the scripts are loaded last, but the icons don't show up!
[image: You can see the chrome network tab here.]

So I was wondering: What is happening here? What am I missing?

Thank you very much for reading my question!

Comment: Then ank my comment up as well please.

Comment: I don't understand what you said, what is 'ank'?

Comment: Just replying to: `First of all **hank** you very much for reading my question!`

Comment: Tell `vue-loader` that you depend on that file explicitly with an `import Icons from '../static/js/uikit-icons.min.js';`  That should force it to be included.

Comment: I tried that, but the scripts aren't imported at all with this

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I have a fix.

Trying to frankenstein this in a vue file didn't work. So I just put this in the index.html

```
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  <script src="static/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
  <script src="static/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

It looks like an easy solution, but I really think I tried it before and it didn't work. But between then and now I learned that the scripts might use jquery so I installed it with npm a couple hours ago. Maybe it fixed it, I really don't know. But my icons are showing without refresh, so i'm happy.